# Is there any anotation to make a Spring data repositories method names shorter?

Tags: spring, annotations, spring-data, method-names

The method names from Spring data repositories may become really long. For example:

```
List<InstanceConfig> findByConfigAppIdAndConfigClusterNameAndConfigNamespaceNameAndDataChangeLastModifiedTimeAfter(
      String appId, String clusterName,
      String namespaceName, Date validDate);
```

I am looking for any annotation that would allow me to do something like this:

```
@XX(key = "findByConfigAppIdAndConfigClusterNameAndConfigNamespaceNameAndDataChangeLastModifiedTimeAfter")
List<InstanceConfig> customMethodName(String appId, String clusterName,
      String namespaceName, Date validDate);
```

Is there any solution to the name length problem?

Comment: I don't want use @Query because don't need write any sql is biggest advantage of spring data. Java8 default grammar can solve my problem but I think it's not a very grace solution.

Comment: Maybe you can add your comment as a requeriment for your question to differ from the other one `:)`

Comment: I'm so sorry. This is my first time ask questions :-D

Comment: No worries `:)`. The question it's now closed but you can edit with the new information and try to reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

With java 8 you can create a `default method` and call the method with the too length name:

```
List<InstanceConfig> findByConfigAppIdAndConfigClusterNameAndConfigNamespaceNameAndDataChangeLastModifiedTimeAfter(String appId, String clusterName,
      String namespaceName, Date validDate);

default List<InstanceConfig> customMethodName(String appId, String clusterName,
      String namespaceName, Date validDate) {
   return findByConfigAppIdAndConfigClusterNameAndConfigNamespaceNameAndDataChangeLastModifiedTimeAfter(appId,clusterName,
     namespaceName, validDate);
}
```

Then if you call `customMethodName` is as you are calling `findByConfigAppIdAndConfigClusterNameAndConfigNamespaceNameAndDataChangeLastModifiedTimeAfter`.

Comment: it's a good solution. But use java 8 features,If spring data provide a feature just like I suggested maybe a better solution?  Anyway thank you very much!

Comment: There is not such feature... Maybe in the future but I don't think so, IMHO It's not needed...

Comment: maybe. But I think it is not grace for code style and friendly for repository client. It's just my person opinion. :-D